# salt-api, using cherry but log from tornado

Tags: tornado, cherrypy, salt-stack

I use rest-cherrypy in salt-api by:

```
rest_cherrypy:
port: 8080
host: 0.0.0.0
...
```

but i see logs about tornado

```
2016-09-18 06:32:11,023 [tornado.application][ERROR ][1499] Exception in callback (<socket._socketobject object at 0x7fffefc334b0>, <function null_wrapper at 0x7fffea71caa0>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 866, in start
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 248, in accept_handler
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 202, in accept
error: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

I have not any other application on this machine.

Comment: Check `ulimit`s in your OS

Comment: @webKnjaZ ulimit out put is 65536 but my broblem is that why tornado create log message when i use cherrypy in salt-api

Comment: I think, it's not related to cherrypy. Check the amount of open file descriptors and connections